# How to Trim and copy the content of a single excell cell to the clipboard with a VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba, copy, trim, removing-whitespace

There's a worker in my office who needs to copy the content of single excel cells without any whitespace arround it to introduce into an ERP, he copies the old Ctrl + V way and excel adds whitespace arround it for some reason,that causes problems in the ERP system, i have this code and i get the following error:

```
Sub Copy(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim text As String
 text = Trim(CStr(Target))
 text.Copy
End Sub
```

And the Error pops up in a warning message box with the following message:

El argumento no es opcional

The argument is not optional (Translation).

Any idea on why this appears or how to fix it?

EDIT: I excecute this macro with a button i added with the customize ribbon option ([basically this](http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/create_a_toolbar_button_or_menu_item_to_run_a_macro.html))

Comment: If this is VBA, string variables are not objects, so cannot have a `.Copy` method.

Comment: You can use VBA to set text in the clipboard via a `DataObject` instance: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/clipboard.aspx

Comment: Ok, so what method could i use to copy the text variable to clipboard?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks i will check it out

Comment: VB is telling me that the Argument is not optional comes from the Range variable, i added this macro to my toolbar with the cutomize ribbon option, i don't know if this has to do with the error

Comment: You can't call that macro without giving it a value for `Target`.  If you want it to pick up the active cell then remove the `ByVal Target As Range` and use `Selection` instead of `Target` in your Sub.  That still doesn't get the text onto the clipboard, but it explains the error you see when you call the macro.

Comment: Yes, it was that, working fine, thank you!